Can not update the Credential in the linked service for ADF
I have a Databricks linked service for ADF in the live mode, Now I want to update the MI Credentials to another one, but I could not change it.
When I selected another Credential, the linked service displayed that it was updated. But when I opened it again after saving, it reverted back to its original Credential. Even after successfully publishing it after saving, when I clicked on the linked service again, it still displayed as the old Credential.
Old Linked service:

Then I change it to another before save the linked service:

However, I re-open it after saving it, it reverted back to its original Credential:

When I save the linked service, I also received the successfully notification:

What is the reason for this issue? Is there any solution for this?
Currently, I could resolved it by re-creating the new linked service. But this is not what I want (we have many linked services).

clear cache of your browser and try again, and refresh the data factory once

@PratikLad, I am using private mode in browser. And I also test it in another PC, still same issue. So, may not related to the cache.

I have also tried the same in my environment, but it worked fine for me
